# Forming a series representation for $\tan^a(u)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

As part of my attempt at solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140495/integral-involving-the-logarithm-of-trigonometric-function/3142176?fbclid=IwAR2AX0PmeNzOhLxNLSlOgS3hGW8rY42A-rfhU_4ImH-2uJFSxIu6A336QmM#3142176) integral, I became stuck with resolve the following definite integral:
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^{\pi/4}u^{b}\tan^a\left(u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u
\nonumber 
\end{equation}
Where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I have no idea how to address this integral in it's current form. My initial thought was to employ a series representation for $\tan^a(u)$ however I have no idea how this could be done. So my question, is it possible to form a series based representation for $\tan^a(u)$?? and if so, what methods can be employed?

Just hoping for a starting point :-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on series expansion, starting from the usual expansion of $\frac{\tan(x)} x$, you have (using the generalized binomial expansion)
$$\left(\frac{\tan (u)}{u}\right)^a=1+\frac{a }{3}u^2+\left(\frac{a^2}{18}+\frac{7 a}{90}\right)
   u^4+\frac{\left(35 a^3+147 a^2+124 a\right) }{5670}u^6+O\left(u^8\right)$$

Trying with $a=\pi$ and $b=e$, this would give $0.04879$ while numerical integration would give $0.04961$. Adding one extra term would lead to $0.04936$.

If you write
$$u^b\,\tan^a(u)=u^{a+b} \left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\, u^{2n}\right)$$ the first coefficients write
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & c_n \\
 1 & \frac{a}{3} \\
 2 & \frac{a^2}{18}+\frac{7 a}{90} \\
 3 & \frac{a^3}{162}+\frac{7 a^2}{270}+\frac{62 a}{2835} \\
 4 & \frac{a^4}{1944}+\frac{7 a^3}{1620}+\frac{3509 a^2}{340200}+\frac{127
   a}{18900} \\
 5 & \frac{a^5}{29160}+\frac{7 a^4}{14580}+\frac{2269 a^3}{1020600}+\frac{2011
   a^2}{510300}+\frac{146 a}{66825} \\
 6 & \frac{a^6}{524880}+\frac{7 a^5}{174960}+\frac{5567 a^4}{18370800}+\frac{10397
   a^3}{10206000}+\frac{5269351 a^2}{3536379000}+\frac{1414477 a}{1915538625} \\
 7 & \frac{a^7}{11022480}+\frac{7 a^6}{2624400}+\frac{1649
   a^5}{55112400}+\frac{14891 a^4}{91854000}+\frac{4683409
   a^3}{10609137000}+\frac{6470969 a^2}{11493231750}+\frac{32764 a}{127702575} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your post. Is there a general expression for $c_n$?

Comment: @DavidG. You are welcome ! I tried to get  a general expression for $c_n$ but no success at all. If $a$ was an integer, they would probably express as very nasty Eler polynomials.

Comment: Sorry, I've not dealt with this method of the series expansion for $\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$. Is this part of a generalised method?

Comment: @DavidG. Take the usual series expansion of $\tan(x)$; divide by $x$ and use the generailized binomial therorem. Try it for $a=2$. As I said earlier, for integer values of $a$ this reduces to Euler polynomials. For $a=2$, the coefficients are $$c_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1} 2^{2 n+2} (2 E_{2 n+3}(-1)+4)}{(2 n+2)!}$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks so much! I'm determined to figure this out! :-)

Comment: @DavidG. Good to know ! Composition of series is really interesting. You can do a lot with it; this is just one case. Cheers :-)

Comment: Cheers, sorry one last question - do you know of any good materials to learn series?

Comment: @DavidG. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627525/recommend-book-taylor-expansions

Comment: Is this question still open?

Answer (score 0):

Substitution
$$\tan u = x$$
gives:
$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}u^b\tan^a u\,\mathrm du
=\int\limits_0^1 x^a\arctan^b x \frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}
=\frac1{b+1}\int\limits_0^1 x^a\,\mathrm d\arctan^{b+1}x$$
$$=\frac1{b+1}x^a\arctan^{b+1}x\bigg|_0^1-\frac a{b+1}\int\limits_0^1 x^{a-1}\arctan^{b+1}x\,\mathrm dx,$$
$$=\frac1{b+1}\left(\frac\pi4\right)^{b+1}-\frac a{b+1}\int\limits_0^1 x^{a-1}\arctan^{b+1}x\,\mathrm dx,$$
wherein [the Taylor series for the arctangent degrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+arctan%5E(b%2B1)+(x)+at+x%3D1%2Fsqrt3) at $x_0=1/\sqrt3$ has [a good convergence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20arctan%5E(b%2B1)%20(x)%20at%20x%3D1.%2Fsqrt3).